# How to write a number in hexadecimal without calculation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have this big number that I want to write in hexadecimal without any calculation.

(10 * 16^2) + (7 * 16^3) + (14 * 16^6) + (16^7)

what I did was I converted it to decimal and then converted it to binary and got this

1E007A00 but my teacher said try to do it without calculation so I got stuck

can anyone please help?

Comment: Hint.  Think about what hex expansion _means_, Then look at the coefficients of the powers of $16$ in the expression. .

Comment: @EthanBolker still can't figure it out without conversion to ether binary or decimal

Comment: Aren't you adding the hexadecimals `0xA00`, `0x7000`, `0xE000000` and `0x10000000` together here? This is grade school addition. There won't even be any carry.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thank you sir hopefully that's the approach my teacher is expecting